# Webpack multi-page public file extraction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I use webpack4, Extracting css using extract-text-webpack-plugin.

```js
// ...
plugins: [
    ...htmls,
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style/[name].[contenthash].css')
]
```

```js
// index.css
// home.css
// about.css
```

It's all okay, Correct output.

Until I use optimization.splitChunks to extract the react and react-dom frameworks.

```js
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            commons: {
                name: 'react',
                chunks: 'all'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now he can only output a css file named react, And includes all the components in the style.

I don't know why this is, how can I solve it?